# Passing data behind Naviagtion Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Hi I have 4 view Controllers
MainVC ----> NavBar ----> MyViewController----->UIWebView

Inside my MainVC based on segue, I want to set different data to tableview controller. Here is my prepareforsegue method

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


  var navController =  segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
  var HVController =  navigationController?.viewControllers[0] as MyViewController
  HVController.somevar = "Something"
}
```

However program crashes. How can I pass data from my MainVC to MyViewController? Thanks.

EDIT: I have found my stupid mistake the code should have been as

```
var HVController =  navController.viewControllers[0] as MyViewController
```

Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Can you post the crash log?

Comment: it just stops at  var HVController =  navigationController?.viewControllers[0] as MyViewController line and says Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION....

Comment: `UIWebView` is a view, not a view controller.

Comment: @Meanteacher Does anything appear in the console?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add a variable in your Target ViewController (MyViewController).

For example:

```
var passValue:String!
```

Then, you can pass value from your current ViewController to the target:

```
if segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifier" {
  (segue.destinationViewController as MyViewController).passValue = yourObjectToPass
}
```

Comment: Stupid me! I had to use var HVController =  navController.viewControllers[0] as MyViewController Why I define something and don't use it. Sorry for wasting your time guys.